# Filter divs by class

Tags: javascript, html, class, filter

I am trying to create a function that returns an additional display of none when you click on a button. It basically filters divs with class names when you click a button. I used a while/do loop to go through all the elements by class name.
In the browser console log it is telling me

> "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined".

Does anybody knows what might be the problem?

```
    <div class="container"> 
      <h1 id="title">World's Top suppply chains</h1>
        <div class="options">
          <button id="allbtn">All</button>
          <button>Drinks</button>
          <button>Clothing</button>
          <button>Cars</button>
          <button id="fast-food-btn">Fast Food</button>
    </div>

    <div class="stores">
        <div class="store">
            <img src="images/adidas.png">
            <h3>Adidas</h3>
            <p class="industry">Clothing</p>
        </div>



        <div class="store">
            <img src="images/corona.png">
            <h3>Corona</h3>
            <p class="industry">Drinks</p>
        </div>


        <div class="store">
            <img src="images/nike.jpg">
            <h3>Nike</h3>
            <p class="industry">Clothing</p>
        </div>

        <div class="store">
            <img src="images/lambo.png">
            <h3>Lamborghini</h3>
            <p class="industry">Cars</p>
        </div>

        <div class="store">
            <img src="images/smirnoff.png">
            <h3>Smirnoff</h3>
            <p class="industry">Drinks</p>
        </div>



        <div class="store">
            <img src="images/pepsi.jpg">
            <h3>Pepsi</h3>
            <p class="industry">Drinks</p>
        </div>


        <div class="store">
            <img src="images/gucci.png">
            <h3>Gucci</h3>
            <p class="industry">Clothing</p>
        </div>

          <div class="store">
            <img src="images/heineken.jpg">
            <h3>Heineken</h3>
            <p class="industry">Drinks</p>
        </div>



        <div class="store">
            <img src="images/lacoste.png">
            <h3>Lacoste</h3>
            <p class="industry">Clothing</p>
        </div>


        <div class="store">
            <img src="images/ferrari.png">
            <h3>Ferrari</h3>
            <p class="industry">Cars</p>
        </div>

      <div class="store">
            <img src="images/pizzahut.png">
            <h3>Pizza Hut</h3>
            <p class="industry">Fast Food</p>
        </div>

      <div class="store">
            <img src="images/cocacola.png">
            <h3>Coca Cola</h3>
            <p class="industry">Drinks</p>
        </div>

        <div class="store">
            <img src="images/mc.png">
            <h3>Mc Donalds</h3>
            <p class="industry">Fast Food</p>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    const industry = document.getElementsByClassName(".industry");
    const fastFood = document.getElementById("fast-food-btn"); 

    allbtn.addEventListener("click", filter);

    function filter(){

        const card = industry.parentElement; 

    do{
         card.style.display = "none";
    }
        while(industry.innerHTML === "Fast Food");
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First issue is that you don't need the dot in front of the class when using `getElementsByClassName`.
Secondly `getElementsByClassName` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which does not have a property called `parent`.

Which results in something like this:

```
function filter() {
    const industries = document.getElementsByClassName("industry");
    for (let industry of industries) {
        industry.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Furthermore, it looks like the variable `fastFood` is not used and the variable `allbtn` is undefined. I assume it shoul be something like this:

```
const allbtn = document.getElementById("allbtn");
```

Putting it together, this should solve your problem:

```
<script>
    function filter() {
        const industries = document.getElementsByClassName("industry");
        for (let industry of industries) {
            industry.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    const allbtn = document.getElementById("allbtn");
    allbtn.addEventListener("click", filter);
</script>
```